GO application, as a windows service, does not generate pdf from html when running chrome headless
Context:
Windows Service -> HTTP GO Application -> "Exec" Package -> CMD Command -> Chrome Headless --print-to-pdf
Summary:
When trying to convert the page "a.html" to "a.pdf" through an HTTP request to a GO server application that, in turn, uses the "exec" package and the Command and Run functions on headless chrome, it does not generate the output of "a.pdf".
However, I believe it is something related to the Windows service because, according to the code provided below, in example "B", creating an executable and running it normally generates the PDF, on the other hand, in example "A", which has code similar to "B" but is an HTTP server installed as a Windows service, it does not generate the output of "a.pdf".
Code:
I put the examples "A" and "B" commented in the same file to make it easier to view and compile for testing.
********* GO *********
package main

import (
    //"os/exec"
    //"net/http"
)

//EXAMPLE A
/*
func F(pResponseWriter http.ResponseWriter, pRequest *http.Request) {

    exec.Command("cmd","/c","chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer").Run()
    
    pResponseWriter.WriteHeader(200)
    pResponseWriter.Write(nil)
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/",F)
    http.ListenAndServe(":[PORT]", nil)
}
*/

//EXAMPLE B

/*
func main() {

    exec.Command("cmd","/c","chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer").Run()
}
*/

********* HTML (a.html) *********
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span> Test </span>
</body>
</html>

Tests I performed without success:
A) Open a new CMD with the "start" command.
exec.Command("cmd","c/","start cmd /c chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer").Run()

B) Point the CMD directory to my desktop through the "Dir" attribute of the "cmd" struct of the "exec" package;
C) Variations in the execution of the command, such as:
exec.Command("cmd /c chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer").Run()

exec.Command("cmd", "chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer").Run()

exec.Command("cmd", "chrome", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html", "--no-pdf-header-footer").Run()

exec.Command("cmd", "chrome", "--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=c:/testChromeHeadless/output/a.pdf c:/testChromeHeadless/input/a.html --no-pdf-header-footer).Run()

D) Setting the service to run with the administrator user;
E) Check the "Allow service to interact with desktop" flag in the "Log On" tab of the Windows service;
Installing the HTTP GO server as a Windows service: https://github.com/winsw/winsw
About Chrome Headless: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/headless?hl=pt-br

Hello. So, what I installed as a service is my GO application (which is a webserver). I'm also using the correct version of headless chrome, requesting to open chrome via cmd.
